# App Script - Send Email based on days left to date - Email content 1st and 2nd - can't display the columns side by side in the sent email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-developer-tools

@NaziA Helped me with this script here.

I am using this to send an automatic email from a spreadsheet when a specific date from a cell is about to be reached (3 days).

As content for the email I am getting a message, a link, and the 1st and 2nd column element that is about to reach a specific date.

My objective here is to display in the output email the 1st and second column together or side by side for easy comparison.

[image: This is my output Email:]

[image: This is my Spreadsheet]

This is the code i'm using:

```
function offboardingReminderV2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set active sheet to first sheet
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2;
  // grab all data from user to days left
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 12);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var users1 = [];
  var users2 = [];

  // loop all data per row
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    // if days left is 3
    if(row[11] == 3) {
      // add user if 3 days left
      users1.push(row[0]);
      users2.push(row[1]);
    }
  });

  // if users has elements
  if(users1) {
    // Formatted the message as html to look nicer
    var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>The following user/s offboarding is due in 3 days</font2></h1><p>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QvJx7AaHT4cPGS6kvfH2Vatpn6jXo4gH1Mae8906ZFQ/edit#gid=372029014:</p>";
    // created bulleted list for list of users
    var emails = "<ul>";
    users1.forEach(function(user){
      emails = emails + "<li>" + user + "</li>";
    });
    
    emails += "</ul>";

  if(users2) {
    // created bulleted list for list of users
    var names = "<ul>";
    users2.forEach(function(user){
      names = names + "<li>" + user + "</li>";
    });
    
    emails += "</ul>";
    names += "</ul>"
    message = message + names + emails + "</body></html>";
    var flexmails = "email@example.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "Reminder Offboarding Control", "", {htmlBody: message, noReply: true});
  }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values from the column "A" and "B" in a tag of `<li>` by arranging the columns.

In this case, I would like to modify the if statement of `if(users1) {}`. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
  if(users1) {
    // Formatted the message as html to look nicer
    var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>The following user/s offboarding is due in 3 days</font2></h1><p>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QvJx7AaHT4cPGS6kvfH2Vatpn6jXo4gH1Mae8906ZFQ/edit#gid=372029014:</p>";
    // created bulleted list for list of users
    var emails = "<ul>";
    users1.forEach(function(user){
      emails = emails + "<li>" + user + "</li>";
    });
    
    emails += "</ul>";

  if(users2) {
    // created bulleted list for list of users
    var names = "<ul>";
    users2.forEach(function(user){
      names = names + "<li>" + user + "</li>";
    });
    
    emails += "</ul>";
    names += "</ul>"
    message = message + names + emails + "</body></html>";
    var flexmails = "email@example.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "Reminder Offboarding Control", "", {htmlBody: message, noReply: true});
  }
}
```

To:

```
if (users1.length > 0 && users2.length > 0) {
  var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>The following user/s offboarding is due in 3 days</font2></h1><p>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit#gid=372029014:</p>";
  var names = "<ul>";
  users2.forEach(function (user, i) {
    names += `<li>${user}, ${users1[i]}</li>`;
  });
  names += "</ul>"
  message = message + names + "</body></html>";
  var flexmails = "email@example.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "Reminder Offboarding Control", "", { htmlBody: message, noReply: true });
}
```

- If you want to replace the columns, please modify `` names += `<li>${user}, ${users1[i]}</li>`; `` to `` names += `<li>${users1[i]}, ${user}</li>`; ``.

Comment: Will do! I don't see the accept answer button though, I think it may be because i'm a new user. If you upvote my question I think I will have enough reputation to validate your answer